# Edit field schema of web layer in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, hosted-feature-layer

I would like to edit the field schema of a web layer in ArcGIS Pro via Design --> Fields but I get the error message **"the table or feature class corresponding to this view is read-only"**.

To clarify, I opened a web layer (Hosted Feature Layer) I have created previously in ArcGIS Pro (Version 2.5.0) using a portal connection. I checked the Editing Status and it says my layer is Editable. However, when I try adding new fields to the layer it says it's read-only. See image below.

Does anyone know what this means and how I can edit the field schema? Note, I have admin rights.

[image]

Comment: i've got the same problem even working with a simple shapefile created in a folder of my Disk. did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A little delayed, but I had the same problem.

I solved it by signing into ArcGIS Pro as the owner of the item.  I had to close the attribute table and re-open before I was able to edit the schema.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I still get the error. I am also signed in as the owner of the item but it still says read-only. Opening or closing the attribute table does not change the error for me. I usually have the attribute table closed as I don't want to change the attribute values, just the schema.